# Coverage of maps of Germany regarding high precision coordinates

Tags: here-api

I'm playing a little with the route matching function of here api i stumbled across ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn layers, whose attributes, especially HPX, HPY and HPZ, sound pretty interesting, because they seem to offer a guaranteed higher precision [10^-7 degree WGS84] than the corresponding attributes from the ROAD_GEOM_FCn layers (WGS84 NTU [degree * 100000]).

However, when querying the attributes of both layers for some route link, say 1225169645, i found that quite often the values of these attributes are the same. For instance for route link 1225169645, these are

- ROAD_GEOM_FCn.LAT: "5292564,346,290,211,106,98,114,107,20"
- ROAD_GEOM_FCn.LON: "817163,158,132,94,47,40,48,43,7"
- ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn.HPX: "81716300,15800,13200,9400,4700,4000,4800,4300,700"
- ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn.HPY:
  "529256400,34600,29000,21100,10600,9800,11400,10700,2000"

Thus, i suspect that the fact that a route link has the above attributes, does not mean that these values have a **guaranteed precision** of 10^-7 degree WGS84 regarding the points along the route link. To be clear, by precision i refer to the deviation from the positions as specified by the map and the real geographic coordinates of the part of the road which the route link represents. I think it is quite unlikely to assume that the values of the attributes mentioned above are equal by pure coincidence. Otherwise this would mean that one does not need the additional two decimal places to describe the actual geographic coordinates of these points (because the last two decimal places are 0 for all coordinates). This applies by the way to a lot of other route links that it have been looking at.
This leads to my question:

Is there any information available regarding the coverage of route links in Germany which have ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn attributes available **AND** where the values of attributes HPX, HPY have a **guaranteed precision** of 10^-7 degree WGS84 regarding the deviation from the real geographic coordinates of the part of the road which the route link represents?

Answer (score 0):

Platform Data Extension(PDE) collects the adas attributes. You can get the coverage information by triggering the below query. We have 100% coverage in Germany(FC1-4). You can also check http://tcs.ext.here.com/ to get more information on the PDE layers and data definitions.

Update: As mentioned in the documentation we have 100% coverage in Germany and all the data you see for HPX,HPY,HPZ have a guaranteed precision of [10^-7 degree WGS84]. You can see the description here https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=18150&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC1

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/maps.json?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

Comment: You have asked about the coverage in this statement. Rephrase it if this is not what you intended to ask - Is there any information available regarding the coverage of maps with high precision coordinates, especially regarding Germany?

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for the answer. I am not sure though whether my question has really been addressed. To make this more precise: I am **not** asking for the coverage of route links in Germany having ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn attributes available. I am asking for the coverage of route links in Germany where these attributes really have a **guaranteed precision** of [10^-7 degree WGS84]. I updated my question to make this more precise.

Comment: Sorry, but this **CANNOT** be true. I agree that all values found in attributes HPX and HPY are given in terms of [10^-7 degree WGS84] units. However, i can specify the exact same geographic coordinate also in terms of  [10^-70 degree WGS84] units by appending a 0 for 63 times. Its still the same number! And to me it looks like for a lot of route links the values of the respective attributes are exactly the same. So it appears that the values of HPX and HPY have just been copied from the imprecise ROAD_GEOM_FCn.LAT and ROAD_GEOM_FCn.LON attributes.